Formula to Filter Top 30 Vendors Based on Total Amount and Date Range
I have this formula, it is working without the date range condition but will show only the heading label if the date condition is added.
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER('Line Items (V3)'!$B$1:$B$17068)), 
   'Line Items (V3)'!$E$1:$E$17068, 
   'Line Items (V3)'!$P$1:$P$17068}, 
  "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col3) 
   WHERE Col2 >= " & DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 5, 1, 1) & "
   GROUP BY Col1 
   ORDER BY SUM(Col3) DESC 
   LIMIT " & $B$3 & " 
   LABEL Col1 'VENDOR NAME', SUM(Col3) 'TOTAL AMOUNT' 
   FORMAT SUM(Col3) '#,##0.00'", 
  1)

Tried revising the date condition with this but still same result:
DATE(" & YEAR(TODAY()) - 5 & ", 1, 1)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share with us the Minimal Reproducible Example for this post in the form of a sample Google Sheets with public access.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Query syntax
Since a minimal reproducible sample has not been provided, I created my own dataset to test the Google sheet function which also gave me the same error.

I came up with a solution to make the date condition work. When using date as condition in “QUERY” formula, best practice is to format it to string “yyyy-MM-dd” first using “TEXT” to be able to parse the date correctly in a query.
You can check the updated formula below:
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER('Line Items (V3)'!$B$1:$B$17068)), 'Line Items (V3)'!$E$1:$E$17068, 'Line Items (V3)'!$P$1:$P$17068}, 
"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col3) 
 WHERE Col2 >= date '" & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 5, 1, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' 
 GROUP BY Col1 
 ORDER BY SUM(Col3) DESC 
 LIMIT " & $B$3 & " 
 LABEL Col1 'VENDOR NAME', SUM(Col3) 'TOTAL AMOUNT' 
 FORMAT SUM(Col3) '#,##0.00'", 1)

I have added and modified the following formula below:
WHERE Col2 >= date '" & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 5, 1, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd")

My sample data consists of “Vendor A-Z” with different “Date” and Amount.

And, here is the result:

Suppose that the “LIMIT " & $B$3 " “ means it should restrict the number to a “top 30”. For testing purposes, I use the number 20 since I created limited data.
Kindly visit these public documentation for your references:

QUERY function
TEXT function

